# Why is $dx_1\wedge dx_2(e_1,e_2)=1$?

Tags: differential-forms, exterior-algebra

This question is about definitions and how to thinks about the exterior algebra and how it relates to the tensor algebra.

Let $V$ be a real vector space, $e_1,\dots,e_n$ a basis of $V$, and $dx_1,\dots,dx_n$ the dual basis.

There are three ways to define $dx_1\wedge dx_2$ in terms of the tensor algebra:

$(A)\quad dx_1\otimes dx_2 - dx_2\otimes dx_1$

$(B)\quad\frac{1}{2}(dx_1\otimes dx_2 - dx_2\otimes dx_1)$

$(C)\quad dx_1\otimes dx_2 \operatorname{mod} I$ (where $I$ is the ideal generated by elements of the form $\alpha\otimes\alpha$)

There are four ways to understand the argument $(e_1,e_2)$:

$(a)\quad e_1\otimes e_2 - e_2\otimes e_1$

$(b)\quad \frac{1}{2}(e_1\otimes e_2 - e_2\otimes e_1)$

$(c)\quad e_1\otimes e_2 \operatorname{mod} I$

$(d)\quad e_1\otimes e_2$

When we make choices, what does $dx_1\wedge dx_2(e_1,e_2)$ evaluate to?
$$ Aa=2, Ab=1, Ac=1, Ad=1$$
$$ Ba=1, Bb=\frac{1}{2}, Bc=\frac{1}{2}, Bd=\frac{1}{2} $$
$$ Ca=1, Cb=\frac{1}{2},  Cc=\operatorname{undefined}, Cd=\operatorname{undefined}$$

So we are left with the options $Ab$, $Ac$, $Ad$, $Ba$ and $Ca$.

What should I choose / How should I think about these issues?

Comment: The reason we sometimes define exterior algebra not as a subspace, but as a quotient space of tensor algebra is the problem of fields with nonzero characteristics (we cannot simply divide by arbitrary numbers). Exterior algebra as a quotient space also used in more general modules over rings.

Comment: Since the comments I was answering to are now deleted, I deleted my comments too. I am still interested in an answer!

Comment: In context of differential geometry ($\operatorname{char} \mathbb R=0$) for dif. forms $\alpha,\beta$ (degrees resp. $p,q$) usually assumed $\alpha\wedge \beta=\frac{(p+q)!}{p!q!}A(\alpha\otimes \beta)$ where $A$ is the alternating operator (containing $(p+q)!$ in the denominator). So, if $dx_i(e_j)=\delta_{ij}$ then $dx_1\wedge dx_2(e_1,e_2)=(dx_1\otimes dx_2-dx_2\otimes dx_1)(e_1,e_2)=1$. P.S. There is the only way to understand the argument $(e_1,e_2)$.